# Why I cannot access the first read char array after reading a series of others in C?

Tags: arrays, c, printf, scanf, c-strings

I wanted to read a phrase and a series of numbers/alphabetic separated by ",". I read the first string then I print it (works fine). I read the first string, read 62 of those series and try to print the first string again and is not working. I tried a lot of methods but none working.

```
    char text[1001];
    scanf("%[^\n]", text);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 62; i++) {
        char alpha[3] = {0}, lit_orig, lit_replace;
        scanf("%s", alpha);
        lit_orig = alpha[0];
        lit_replace = alpha[2];
    }

    printf("\n%s", text);
```

Input example:

```
Example text here!
a,H b,j c,6 d,I e,2 f,R g,5 h,t i,h j,k k,m l,f m,D n,F o,1 p,0 q,c r,G s,n t,N u,e v,B w,r x,U y,p z,A A,8 B,X C,S D,P E,T F,a G,M H,d I,K J,L K,3 L,C M,i N,9 O,E P,w Q,o R,z S,4 T,O U,q V,V W,J X,x Y,Z Z,u 0,l 1,y 2,W 3,s 4,Q 5,g 6,v 7,7 8,b 9,Y
```

Output example: There is no output.

I did expect it to print just fine the first string called "text" but it is not working. I tried even clearing out the buffer using getchar() but no results (this is what other websites said it would work). Can you explain what is wrong with my code?

Comment: What are the symptoms of "it is not working"? Please provide a [mre] to demonstrate them, along with the specific input you use.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. The MRE I guessed from the shown code works fine (I just reduced the loop to 3 iterations, because entering that much stuff was annoying). I get the first input (the one before the loop) echoed just fine. I did of course nothing foolish like entering more than two characters for any iteration.

Comment: I see you edit. So you do enter too many characters for your input inside the loop.

Comment: I have updated the question. There is the input I am trying to pass and the output witch in my case is inexistent.

Comment: I dont think there is a problem with the loop... I did print them and they show just fine.

Comment: Interesting, you were not surprised by the presence and location of white space in your echo of what you read? I get an echo of `( a,H)( b,j)` for the first two triplets. And I cannot imagine that you expected that to be what you scan. ( The "()" inserted for debuggin as I propose in my answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account this code snippet

```
    lit_orig = alpha[0];
    lit_replace = alpha[2];
```

where there is used the index equal to `2` it seems that in the call of `scanf`

```
scanf("%s", alpha);
```

you are entering three characters. As a result the terminating zero character `'\0'` is written outside the array `alpha` in the memory occupied by the array `text`. As a result the array `text` contains an empty string.

You need to declare the array `alpha` at least like

```
char alpha[4] = {0},
```

And use the format string in the call of `scanf` the following way

```
scanf("%3s", alpha);
```

Comment: It actually does. Now it is working. I will search about this thing. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your alpha is too small for what you are doing.
Change to `char alpha[5]` for a quick fix.
Insert an output inside your loop to be aware of what is happening.
`printf ("(%4s)", alpha);`

Then fine tune your access and use of `alpha`.
Note the "()" I added to the debug output, to make sure that you see whether/where white space is. I think it might surprise you.